# Forgetting Cofree annotations using a catamorphism

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, category-theory, recursion-schemes, catamorphism

I have an AST that I'm annotating using `Cofree`:

```
data ExprF a
  = Const Int
  | Add a
        a
  | Mul a
        a
  deriving (Show, Eq, Functor)
```

I use `type Expr = Fix ExprF` to represent untagged ASTs, and `type AnnExpr a = Cofree ExprF a` to represent tagged ones.  I've figured out a function to transform tagged ASTs into untagged ones by throwing away all the annotations:

```
forget :: Functor f => Cofree f a -> Fix f
forget = Fix . fmap uncofree . unwrap
```

This looks like it might be some sort of catamorphism (I'm using the definition from Kmett's [recursion-schemes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-5.0.2/docs/Data-Functor-Foldable.html#v:cata) package).

```
cata :: (Base t a -> a) -> t -> a
cata f = c where c = f . fmap c . project
```

I'd think the above rewritten using a catamorphism would look something like this, but I can't figure out what to put for `alg` to make it typecheck.

```
forget :: Functor f => Cofree f a -> Fix f
forget = cata alg where
  alg = ???
```

Any help figuring out if this really is a cata/anamorphism, and some intuition for why it is/isn't would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In order to use `cata` for this, you need to write an algebra from the pattern functor of `Cofree` (that is, `CofreeF`) to `Fix ExprF`. Looks like `tailF` would be helpful for this:

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.12.4/docs/src/Control-Comonad-Trans-Cofree.html#tailF

If nobody else responds before, I'll answer with more details soon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import Data.Functor.Foldable (cata)
import Control.Comonad.Cofree (Cofree)
import Control.Comonad.Trans.Cofree as CofreeT (CofreeF(..))
import Data.Fix (Fix(..))

forget :: Functor f => Cofree f a -> Fix f
forget = cata (\(_ CofreeT.:< z) -> Fix z)
```

N.B.: be careful where `Cofree` and `:<` are imported from.
One is from `Control.Comonad.Cofree`, the other from `Control.Comonad.Trans.Cofree` (as part of the `CofreeF` data type).

If you import `Cofree` from `....Trans.Cofree` instead, the `cata` looks like this instead:

```
import Data.Functor.Identity (Identity(..))
import Data.Functor.Compose (Compose(..))
import Data.Functor.Foldable (cata)
import Control.Comonad.Trans.Cofree as CofreeT (Cofree, CofreeF(..))
import Data.Fix (Fix(..))

forget :: Functor f => Cofree f a -> Fix f
forget = cata (\(Compose (Identity (_ CofreeT.:< z))) -> Fix z)
```

#### Explanation

Looking only at the types, we can show that there is really only one way to implement `forget`. Let's start with the type of `cata`:

```
cata :: Recursive t => (Base t b -> b) -> t -> b
```

Here `t ~ Cofree f a` and the [type instance of `Base` for `Cofree`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-5.0.2/docs/src/Data-Functor-Foldable.html#line-347) gives:

```
type instance Base (Cofree f a) = CofreeF f a
```

Where [`CofreeF`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.12.4/docs/Control-Comonad-Trans-Cofree.html#t:CofreeF) is:

```
data CoFreeF f a b = a :< f b
-- N.B.: CoFree also defines a (:<) constructor so you have to be
-- careful with imports.
```

i.e., a fancy pair type. Let's replace it with an actual pair type to make things clearer:

```
cata :: Functor f => ((a, f b) -> b) -> Cofree f a -> b
```

Now we're really specializing `cata` with a more concrete `b`, namely `Fix f`:

```
-- expected type of `cata` in `forget`
cata :: Functor f => ((a, f (Fix f)) -> Fix f) -> Cofree f a -> Fix f
```

`forget` is parametric in `a` and `f`, so the function we give `cata` can do nothing with the `a` in the pair, and the only sensible way to implement the remaining `f (Fix f) -> Fix f` is the `Fix` wrapper.

Operationally, `Fix` is the identity, so `(\(_ :< z) -> Fix z)` is really `(\(_ :< z) -> z)` which corresponds to the intuition of removing the annotation, i.e., the first component of the pair `(_ :< z)`.

Comment: I knew I'd gotten something wrong with the `Cofree` vs. `CofreeF` situation!  All I needed to do was change the pattern match on `:<` to a pattern match on `:<` from the `Control.Comonad.Trans.Cofree` module.  Thank you!

Comment: Indeed, you were very close!

Comment: This answer no longer seems to work, the `\(_ :< z) -> ...` pattern match gives rise to this error:  `Couldn't match type: CofreeF f a0 (Fix f) with: Data.Functor.Compose.Compose` `Data.Functor.Identity.Identity (CofreeF f a) (Fix f)` `Expected: Base (Cofree f a) (Fix f)` `Actual: CofreeF f a0 (Fix f)`.  Perhaps one of the dependencies has changed?

Comment: I updated my answer to clarify where things must be imported from.